# How can read data from Kepware server

Tags: plc, opc

I would like to development a client app to read data from machine PLC. On this machine there is a bridge pc that have the Kepware server installed, so if I run kepware client demo toolkit I can read the value of machine. So I would like to development a client for read data from this machine.

I have find this program online but I have a problem with library when I try to run it

http://support.automation.siemens.com/WW/llisapi.dll?func=cslib.csinfo&objId=25229521&lang=en&siteid=cseus&aktprim=0&objaction=csview&extranet=standard&viewreg=WW

I see the comunication is on OPC Protocol (OLE for Process Control).

Can we help me?

Comment: On which platform will your client run - is it Windows? Which tools or languages can you possibly use - do you truly want to get the data into Excel as in the example you pointed to, or are you developing a program e.g. in C++, C#, VB.NET ?

Comment: Run on Windows. I can use Excel, C# is not important. I must extracd data.

Comment: Kepware, provides a HDA client that can be used for historical data access. Their client is capable of directly writing into excel file. Matrikon also has tools that do this

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply, but I not find this function. Can you help me to find that?? So I have see KeepwareServerEX and I have see this function "menu Tools -> Launch OPC Quick Client" I don't find HDA Client

Comment: @bircastri: You can use OPCLabs "QuickOPC Data classic" client to read the data from Kepware server.

Comment: Ok, but with "QuickOPC Data classic" I can stored the data? I must save data and I can't only read data.

Comment: Do you want to store the data in DataBase? If yes, it is possible.

Comment: Excuse me but I think if not necessary use QuickOPC Data classic becaus I must use C#, C++ or VB for development a client for read from OPC Server. So can we help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install **QuickOPC 5.23(.NET Framework 3.5 or 4.0)** or **QuickOPC 5.31(.NET Framework 4.5)** from **http://opclabs.com/products/quickopc/downloads**

Create a **VB.NET** project in VisualStudio.

Add the reference, **OpcLabs.EasyOpcClassic.dll** to the project.

[image]

Use the following code to read data from **Kepware server** using VB.NET

```vb
Imports OpcLabs.EasyOpc
Imports OpcLabs.EasyOpc.DataAccess

Public Class Demand
    Private Sub frm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ReadPLCvalue()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReadPLCvalue()
        Dim objClient As New EasyDAClient
        Dim sValue As Object

        Try
            sValue = objClient.ReadItemValue(KepwareServerMachineName, KepwareServerID, PLCTagName)
        Catch ex As OpcException

        End Try

        StoreToDB(sValue)
    End Sub

    Private Sub StoreToDB(ByVal source As Object)
      'Database operations to store the value.
    End Sub
End Class
```